# Sample file for grep

Tags: linux, debian, grep

Can anyone please point to some good sample files that helps to learn grep. This is for academic use. It should be a large one so that students could understand its importance

Comment: Perhaps `/usr/share/dict`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file `/etc/services` contains a list of known services. It is too long to read through, and it might be a good real world example of when to use grep.

```
linux@host$ cat /etc/services | grep 'http'
```

To demonstrate how to find out which port http uses, or

```
linux@host$ grep '80/tcp' /etc/services
```

To find out what service you can expect to find on port 80

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use books from [Project Gutenberg](http://www.gutenberg.org/). They are in the public domain, are quite large (you can `cat` some books together if desired) and can be used to devise many real-world examples of grep.

Otherwise, Wikipedia gives [a bunch of public domain resources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aPublic_domain_resources#Computer_science) which might be available in plain text format.